# Did Luke ever try podracing?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, luke-skywalker, tatooine

We know that Anakin Skywalker was a successful podracer on Tatooine. Did his son Luke, who also grew up on Tatooine (though without knowing the correct and full back-story of his father) ever try podracing? We know that Luke had piloting aptitude, flew a T-16, and was force-sensitive like his father, so it stands to reason that he might have become a decent podracer if he had tried. Is this ever explored anywhere? Was podracing no longer a "thing" by the time of Luke's childhood on Tatooine? Was the Lars' farm too far away for Luke to participate? Did Luke decide not to try it for some reason (e.g. led by the Force, felt it was too dangerous, too busy with other activities)? Did Aunt Beru or Uncle Owen positively forbid Luke from trying it out?

Comment: I hope that no execs at Disney Enterprises have thought of this — else we'll be getting a new rerelease soon, and maybe a spin–off series:  _Young Luke, Podracer_

Comment: I know nothing of any in-canon reference to this, but my personal understanding of Star Wars makes me 99.99% that it's the last option.

Comment: Obi-Wan must have put some effort in preventing Luke from podracing, if it was necessary. Two Skywalkers being victorious in the same race could have arisen some unwanted questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, he did. Luke participated in the [Muunilinst Podrace event](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Muunilinst_Podrace) in 0 ABY and came out victorious. The race was covered in a young-readers novel, [Rebel Force: Target](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rebel_Force:_Target).

The following summary can be found in [The Essential Reader's Companion](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Reader's_Companion):

> In the weeks after the Battle of Yavin, the Emperor makes discovering
>   the identity of the Rebel pilot who destroyed the Death Star of
>   paramount importance.
>
> [...]
>
> To that end, Luke finds himself competing in a dangerous Podrace. He
>   succeeds, and Tobin’s continuing assistance throughout the mission
>   earns the trust of the Rebels. X-7, having witnessed Luke’s piloting
>   skills, begins to suspect that Skywalker is the one the Emperor seeks.
>
> [...]
>
> These tales are some of the few from this point in the time line that
>   benefit from full knowledge of the events of Episodes I through III.
>   As such, Luke’s Podrace competition is a deliberate nod to his
>   father’s Boonta Eve victory.